How can I ensure a non-virtual method returns a specific value when called from a virtual method in google mocks
I'm testing a class AnimalKeeper that has both virtual and non-virtual methods. In my test, I want to call the real AddAnimals method, which is virtual, and ensure that the internal RecordAnimal method (non-virtual) always returns true. Note that AddAnimals calss RecordAnimal(). I tried this way, and I noticed when debugging that the real RecordAnimal() gets called.
 class MockAnimalKeeper : public AnimalKeeper {
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD0(RecordAnimal, bool());
    
        MockAnimalKeeper(ZooTransport::IAnimalConnection* animalConnection,
            : AnimalKeeper(animalConnection) {}
    
    };
    
    
    
    //  the test fixture class
    class AnimalKeeperTest : public testing::Test {
    protected:
        ZooTransport::IAnimalConnection* animalConnection;
        MockAnimalKeeper* mockAnimalKeeper;
    
        void SetUp() override {
            animalConnection = new AnimalConnection();
            mockAnimalKeeper = new MockAnimalKeeper(animalConnection));
        }
    
        void TearDown() override {
            delete mockAnimalKeeper;
        }
    };
    
    TEST_F(AnimalKeeperTest, InvokeSend) {
    
        ON_CALL(*mockAnimalKeeper, RecordAnimal()).WillByDefault(testing::Return(1));
    
        mockAnimalKeeper->AddAnimals();
    }


You can only mock virtual functions (with dynamic polymorphism).
